# pct_change() not working on dataframe. str & str error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm calculating returns of stock prices of PG & BEI.DE

returns = frame.pct_change() unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' ERROR. The work around I have is making dictionary then pass each column in dictionary and apply functions like pct_change, mean or media or cov.

In examples I'm following the instructor applies functions directly on dataframe. Why my data cells are being treated as strings instead of numbers?
I have a work around but I'm not satisfied with it?

Comment: It’s probably because you have strings and not numbers. Try frame.astype(float).pct_change(). If that doesn’t work try frame.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors=‘coerce’)

Comment: I have a column of Dates, none of the suggested solutions working :(
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2018-02-02'

Comment: How can I truncate the Date column?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with a pandas DataFrame, then I'd start by calling `info` on the DataFrame.

```
In [1]: type(frame)
Out[1]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [2]: frame.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Close    5 non-null object
Date     5 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
```

Here we have a DataFrame but the closing price is not a numeric value. So we can calculate the pct_change directly into a new column of the DataFrame by coercing the 'Close' column to a float, like this:

```
In [3]: frame['% change'] = frame['Close'].astype(float).pct_change()

In [4]: frame
Out[4]: 
    Close        Date  % change
0  167.96  2018-01-29       NaN
1  166.97  2018-01-30 -0.005894
2  167.43  2018-01-31  0.002755
3  167.78  2018-02-01  0.002090
4  160.37  2018-02-02 -0.044165
```

But you probably wanted to wrangle your DataFrame into the correct types to begin with... so you could do the following:

```
In [5]: frame['Close'] = frame['Close'].astype(float)
In [6]: frame['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(frame['Date'])
In [7]: frame.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
In [8]: frame.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 5 entries, 2018-01-29 to 2018-02-02
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Close       5 non-null float64
% change    4 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes
```